# Дайте или давайте

Tags: глаголы

> Значит, они стали переходить через мост. Дайте, мы вам объясним. Видите ли, товарищ, это так называемые павловские собаки. Была легенда, мы полагаем, что это только легенда, которая рассказывает о том, что в Институте физиологии имени Павлова жили экспериментальные собаки…

Меня всегда учили, что как соответствие *let's* используется слово *давай/давайте*. Здесь я встретил вместо этого *дай/дайте*.

Есть ли какое-то различие между этими глаголами?

Comment: This is a little bit ungrammatical. It's either *дайте нам объяснить* or *давайте мы вам объясним*. Otherwise, see @user4419802's answer below.

Comment: @Quassnoi *дай объясню* is fine in colloquial speech, though. But this plural is unusual. The bad punctuation (extra comma after *дайте*) doesn't help either.

Comment: If there is the comma, after *"Дайте,"* then I read the verb *"дайте"* as "Let us pass". If no comma, then I read as *"Let __we__ do smth."*

Answer (score 4):

*Дай* - это императив от глагола *дать* (совершенный вид), а *давай* - императив от *давать* (несовершенный вид).

Грубо говоря, *дай* = дай сделать **мне**, а *давай* = давай сделаем **вместе** (иногда также, сделай **сам**).

P.S. Да, вместо *дайте мы вам объясним*, нужно говорить *давайте мы вам объясним*, но это одна из тех "разговорных" ошибок на грани просторечия, которые время от времени допускают почти все носители языка. В данном случае, возможно, текст был стилизован под разговорную речь, возможно также, что там велось повествование от имени некоего не слишком интеллигентного субъекта и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

```
Дайте мы объясним (выполним, сделаем, ...)
 Give us the function of explanation (execution, doing, ...)
 Hand over the function of (...) to us.


Давайте мы объясним (выполним, сделаем, ...)
 Let us explain (execute, do, ...) that.


 Give me a chance to explain...
Дайте мне шанс объясниться... 


 Let me explain...
Давайте я поясню...
```

В приведенных выше примерах Вы не можете заменить <kbd>Давайте</kbd><≠><kbd>Дайте</kbd>

```
 May I explain that?
             \ ____________with emphasis on
              \
Давайте я объясню это?



 May I explain that?
      \ __________________with emphasis on
       \
Дайте я это объясню.
         \
Позвольте мне это объяснить?
```

В этих примерах возможна замена <kbd>Давайте</kbd><=><kbd>Дайте</kbd> , если смысловой [акцент, усиление, ударение] сделан типографически.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the answer by Avtokod. I do not think it is ungrammatical besides the excessive comma.

There is some difference in meaning. As Avtokod says дайте is more used when hand over of a function is requested. It impyes the action will be done by the speaker without participation of the addressee. In this context I would understand it as the speaker requests the addressee to mute and keep quiet until he finishes the explanation rather than actively participate, ask questions etc.

> Давайте я вам объясню = Let me explain this to you with your
>   participation (you can ask questions in the process etc).
>
> Дайте я вам объясню = Allow me to explain this, do not interrupt me
>   please. Please keep quiet, allow me to talk. You will understand everything after I finished so please do not ask questions until I stopped.